# How do I get email from selected ListItem which is an object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox which displays first and last name. The listbox has 16 objects and displays 16 names. 
Each item in the list is an object. Each object has a name which is displayed in the listbox. The object also have an email. My question is, how do I get the email of the selected name in the listbox and put it in a string? Later I will use this variable to send an email to any selected name in the listbox.

The problem with my code is that ListItem.ToString()) holds a name that is displayed and not email. 
For example Joe Doe is selected name (ListItem) in the listbox. The email of Joe Doe is inside the object. When I hover over the staffEmails which has 16 objects, I find Joe Doe email by copying Expression. Here is the expression for Joe Doe email

```
(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView
    <FTACaseReset.Models.GetRequestorInfoModel>(staffEmails).Items[1]).Email



mailMessage.To.Add(to);
List<GetRequestorInfoModel> staffEmails = new List<GetRequestorInfoModel>();
staffEmails = 
    await FTACaseReset.Controllers.RequestorInfoController.GetAllRequestorInfoes();
ListBoxItem staffEmail = new ListBoxItem();
staffEmail.Text = staffEmails[0].Email;

foreach (var ListItem in MyListBox.SelectedItems)
{
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(ListItem.ToString());
}
```

Here is the code on how I populate the listbox

```
public async void PopulateAdditionalStaffEmailListBox()
    {
        List<GetRequestorInfoModel> staffEmails = new List<GetRequestorInfoModel>();
        try
        {
            staffEmails = await FTACaseReset.Controllers.RequestorInfoController.GetAllRequestorInfoes();
            staffEmails = staffEmails.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < staffEmails.Count; i++)
            {
                ListBoxItem staffEmail = new ListBoxItem();
                staffEmail.Text = staffEmails[i].DisplayName;
                staffEmail.Text = staffEmails[i].Email;
                AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.Items.Add(staffEmail.Text).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView* oh, dear. No. Also, it's unclear what type of ListItem we're talking about here. There are several in the framework. I'm unsure which it is but look for a Text or Value property on it. You're obviously debugging, so when debugging do a quickwatch on the variable and examine it's properties.

Comment: How did you populate the ListBox? Please show code for how you populated the ListBox. You can **edit your question** and paste the code into your question. Please don't put the code in a comment. Is this WPF or winforms?

Comment: It is a Windows application forms. I am not sure how much code you want me to add here on how I populate. I will add the code in the main question under what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing some guessing here as to your environment but you could try...

...populate the listbox using the Value property to store the email...

```
staffEmail.Text = staffEmails[i].DisplayName;
staffEmail.Value = staffEmails[i].Email; // set Value property to be email
```

.. and when sending the email...

```
foreach (var ListItem in MyListBox.SelectedItems)
{
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(ListItem.Value.ToString()); // get email from Value property
}
```

Comment: Tag is not available for me to use. When I click dot after staffEmail. Here is what is available Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, Text, ToString Value

Comment: Then try to use the Value field. I've update my answer. Also, is this a WinForm application and are you using a Third Party control library?

Comment: Generally a drop list will have a display/text property and a backend key/value property.

Comment: When I use the value in the MailAddress, I get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: When you listed the properties of teh staffEmail object I guess I took the final 'Value' in your comment as one of the property names.

Comment: Value is available, however when I use Value  in MailAddress to =new MailAddress(ListItem.Value.ToString()) I am getting o'object does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)